# Program not running at all

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to complete this challenge:

> Write a program that allows the user to enter the grade scored in a
>   programming class (0-100). If the user scored a 100 then notify the
>   user that they got a perfect score.
>
> ★ Modify the program so that if the user scored a 90-100 it informs
>   the user that they scored an A
>
> ★★ Modify the program so that it will notify the user of their letter
>   grade 0-59 F 60-69 D 70-79 C 80-89 B 90-100 A

What I've tried so far is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
a = lambda: random.randint(0, 100)

if a == 100:
    print "You have a perfect score"

if a == range(90, 99):
    print "You have scored an A"

if a == range(80, 89):
    print "You have scored a B"

if a == range(70, 79):
    print "You have scored a C"

if a == range(60, 69):
    print "You have scored a D"

if a == range(0, 59):
    print "You have scored an F"
```

Not sure what I did wrong but I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and this is what happens when I try to run it in terminal:

> blurr@blurr-pc:~/code$ chmod u+x gradingprogram.py
>
> blurr@blurr-pc:~/code$ ./gradingprogram.py

The program doesn't run at all.

Comment: close... use the keyword "in" to determine if a belong to range(x,y)

Comment: `a` is a function. You have to call it.

Comment: From the other comments you might be confusing not running with not giving any output. You can try putting `print "Grading program"` as the first line after the shebang to make sure it is actually executing. If that appears when you run it then you have a logic/code problem not an execution problem.

Comment: @DorianFM I tried that and you were right! It was executed, just not giving output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `a` is a function, so you shouldn't try to compare it to a number.  Call the function and assign it to a variable. `grade = a();`

Second you can check if a number is in a range with `number > lower and number < upper`

You can also use `print` statements to help debug you code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
a = lambda: random.randint(0, 100)
print a

grade = a()
print grade

if grade == 100:
    print "You have a perfect score"

if grade >= 90 and grade < 100:
    print "You have scored an A"

if grade >= 80 and grade <= 89:
    print "You have scored a B"

if grade >= 70 and grade <= 79:
    print "You have scored a C"

if grade >= 60 and grade <= 69:
    print "You have scored a D"

if grade < 59:
    print "You have scored an F"
```

Comment: This is the answer I used, thanks! I removed lambda and grade = a(); and used the same code, replacing the "grade" with "a" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The program does run, but is does not generate any output, because you are in fact comparing a function to a list, so none of the `if` statements apply. There are a few problems with your code:

1. `a` is a function for generating a random number, not the random number itself. Either remove the `lambda:`, or call `a()` and assign the result to some variable.
2. If you want to actually have the user input a number, use `a = int(raw_input())`
3. If you want to check whether `a` is in the range, use the `in` keyword, i.e., `if a in range(90, 99)`, or better (more efficient), use `if 90 <= a < 100`

Comment: I wish I could choose 2 answers because you helped me a lot too. You explained what SethB basically gave an example of in code. Thanks!

Comment: @user3438112 You can always come back when you have enough reputation to upvote. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `type(a)` is `function` - so as @tobias_k says, you have to call it.

```
func = lambda: random.randint(0, 100)
a = func()
...

# alternatively
a = (lambda: random.randint(0,100))()
....
```

would *almost* fix it up.

You'll also need to check you're within a range differently then you have here.

Example:

```
if a >= lower_bound and a <= upper_bound:
    # within range
```

Comment: No, it wouldn't; do you see why?  (Hint: what is `a` being compared to?)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I understand the "= func()" better now.